# WebSocket in Anguar 15

Tags: angular, websocket

I am trying to create Websocket service class in Angular project. I followed multiple tutorials but no one is working. Currently I am trying to implement following [Link](https://indepth.dev/tutorials/angular/how-to-implement-websockets-in-angular-project) but still it is throwing error.

Also, if there is any better way to implement websocket service in angular 15?

## WebSocket Service Class:

```
// src\app\services\websocket.service.ts
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';
import { AnonymousSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const CHAT_URL = "ws://localhost:5000";

export interface Message {
  source: string;
  content: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {
  private subject: AnonymousSubject<MessageEvent> | undefined;
  public messages: Subject<Message>;

  constructor() {
    this.messages = <Subject<Message>>this.connect(CHAT_URL).pipe(
      map(
        (response: MessageEvent): Message => {
          console.log(response.data);
          let data = JSON.parse(response.data)
          return data;
        }
      )
    );
  }

  public connect(url: string): AnonymousSubject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(url);
      console.log("Successfully connected: " + url);
    }
    return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url: string): AnonymousSubject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(url);
    let observable = new Observable((obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
      ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
      ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
      ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
      return ws.close.bind(ws);
    });
    let observer = {
      error: null,
      complete: null,
      next: (data: Object) => {
        console.log('Message sent to websocket: ', data);
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      }
    };
    
    return new AnonymousSubject<MessageEvent>(observer, observable);
  }
}
```

## Error:

Getting error on this line:

```
return new AnonymousSubject<MessageEvent>(observer, observable);
```

[image]

Comment: `Type null is not assignable to type (err: any) => void`, try doing like this: `error: e => console.log(e)`

Comment: no its not working.

Comment: error is still the same? update plz topic with ur changes

Answer (score 1):

you can change the observer like this

```
let observer = {
            error: ()=>{},
            complete:()=> {},
            next: (data: Object) => {
                console.log('Message sent to websocket: ', data);
                if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
private create(url: string): AnonymousSubject<MessageEvent> {
    const ws: WebSocket = new WebSocket(url);
    const observable: Observable<MessageEvent> = new Observable((obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
      ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
      ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
      ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
      return ws.close.bind(ws);
    });
    const observer: Observer<MessageEvent> = {
      error: () => {},
      complete: () => {},
      next: (data: Object) => ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN ? ws.send(JSON.stringify(data)) : null
    };
    return new AnonymousSubject<MessageEvent<any>>(observer, observable);
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).